# Ordinary differential equation - second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $$y''-6y'+25y=50t^3-36t^2 -63t +18$$

I tried solving the homogeneous equation using $y = vt$,  but I didn't go anywhere.

Comment: What exactly do you think the homogeneous equation is? There are two types of "homogeneous" in use in differential equations, linear homogeneous in $y$ as in this case and degree-homogeneous as polynomial or rational function in $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

$ y=vt$ is a wrong "Ansatz" .

The correct "Ansatz" is $y(t)= e^{\lambda t}.$ This leads to

$$\lambda^2-6 \lambda +25=0.$$

Hence $ \lambda = 3\pm 4i$. Therefore the general solution of the homogeneous equation is given by:

$$ y(t)=c_1e^{3t} \cos (4t)+c_2e^{3t} \sin (4t), $$

where $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: What of the right side of the equation??

Answer (score 0):

$$y=y_h+y_p$$
$$y_h=c_1e^{3t} \cos (4t)+c_2e^{3t} \sin (4t)$$
$$y_p=At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D=2t^3-3t$$
Then
$$y=c_1e^{3t} \cos (4t)+c_2e^{3t} \sin (4t)+2t^3-3t$$